# Filter an array from another array of elements and return specific positions

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm finally learning better methods for my JS. I'm trying to find a way to go faster than I do so far :

In my code, I have two arrays :

- one with unique keys in first position
- one with those keys in first position but not unique. There are multiple entries with a certain value I want to filter.

The thing is I don't want to filter everything that is in the second array. I want to select some positions, like item[1]+item[5]+item[6]. What I do works, but I wonder if there isn't a faster way to do it ?

```
    for (let i=0;i<firstArrayOfUniques.length;i++){
      const findRef = secondArrayOfMultiple
        .filter(item => item[0]==firstArrayOfUniques[i][0]);

       // Afterwards, I redo a map and select only the second element, 
       //then I join the multiple answers
       // Is there a way to do all that in the first filter?

       const refSliced = findRef.map(x=>x[1]);
       const refJoin = refSliced.join(" - ");
       canevasSheet.getRange(1+i,1).setValue(refJoin);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] and show inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by an array "_with unique keys in first position_". The first "position" of an array is the position with an index of zero: `myArray[0]`. So, how does that "position" contain "unique keys"? And what does the rest of the array contain? Show us an example! Also, what does "_one with those keys in first position but not unique_" mean? Again, this is not clear, to me. It's great that you provide a _description_ of your data structures - but why don't show us some _examples_, as well? Without seeing the data, your code is difficult to understand.

Comment: If your code actually works, then what is the specific _problem_? Is it too slow? Is it hard to maintain? Some other problem? Stack Overflow tries to focus on solving problems. Maybe you can take a look at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you think your question (finding a way to "go faster") is a good fit for that site, you can ask it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script snippet you quote will spend almost all of its running time calling the `Range.setValue()` method. It gets called separately for every data row. Use `Range.setValues()` instead, and call it just once, like this:

```
function moot(firstArrayOfUniques, secondArrayOfMultiple) {
  const result = firstArrayOfUniques.map(uniqueRow =>
    secondArrayOfMultiple
      .filter(row => row[0] === uniqueRow[0])
      .map(row => row[1])
      .join(' - '));
  canevasSheet.getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```

See [Apps Script best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).

Comment: Thank you so much for this snippet ! I'm learning good things with your constructive post !

Comment: Got it, I'm new to Stack indeed... Some answers feel a bit intense to me who knows very little, but I'm sure there's plenty of knowledge to benefit from